# How to optimize this MySQL reporting query on time range and aggregation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a calendar system for events. Each event has a start date and an end date.
So it's fairly easy to know how many events are active on a certain day.

However producing a report of events active on each day prove to be challenging on a period of 10 years and almost 200'000 events.

The query I tried looks like this

```
select  calendar.day, count(*) 
from 
   calendar, events
where 
   event.startDate <= calendar.day
   and event.endDate>= calendar.day
group by day
```

Calendar table contains 10 years calendar days. I have indexes on start/enddate and day.

200'000 events on 10 years period gives me > 16 sec.
I need to bring this down.

I'm not sure it's possible to do it with a simple query optimization.

Obvious solution probably is to change my code and update a precalculated table every add/update/delete of an event. Other ideas without code change I don't know.

Comment: 16 seconds doesn't seem so bad for what you are doing.  Why do you need the entire period?  Also, what version of MySQL are you using and how long are the events?

Comment: and you really need these counts for every single day in 10 years?

Comment: Agreed, why do you need 10 years worth of data all at once? Surely no-one is actually looking through all of that data every time they use the report?

Comment: Why not just run this query every night to update a count table with that day's count? Surely the number of events per day doesn't change after the day has finished?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: well actually everybody is right, I don't need all the data but I was planning to feed that query to grafana in order to generate graphs. That is the worst case possible, but I thought it was anyway slow

Comment: The charting application should not have problems with missing dates. But if it can do running sums then you can generate +1 and -1 for each start and stop date and the application could sum them to count events.

Answer (score 1):

be sure you have proper index calendar.day too .

```
select  calendar.day, count(*) 
from  calendar
Inner join  events ON  
   event.startDate <= calendar.day
   and event.endDate>= calendar.day
group by day
```

and (not for performance but for clarity) don't use old implict join sintax 
use explicit join instead